# Independent Brownian motions question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $B$ and $W$ be independent Brownian Motions and let $\tau$ be a stopping time of $W$.

Is it true that $E[\int_0^{\tau} B_s \, dW_s] = 0\text{ ?}$

So far I have tried the following:

The integral above is equal to $B_\tau W_\tau - \int_0^\tau W_s \, dB_s$ by Ito.
I want to show that there is a stopping time $\tau$ such that $W_\tau = 0$ and $E[|\int_0^\tau W_s \, dB_s|] = \infty$ I'm not even sure I can do this though.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $-B_s$ has exactly the same distribution as $B_s$, this expectation must be its own additive inverse.

Comment: My problem is that the integral may not be in $L^1$. i.e. there may be a stopping time that makes the integral not in $L^1$ so that the expectation does not exist.

Comment: Good point.  Which means I was write to keep this in comments.  The symmetry I mentioned proves that _if_ there is an expected value, then it is $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Note that if $E[\tau^2]<\infty$ that we have that it is indeed $0$ by the BDG inequality.

Comment: I have a ...write... to make mistakes in mere "comments".